# creating table in sql-server using python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I need to write a python program to create a table and add columns to it but the name and the quantity of tables and its columns will we user defined means I don't know the name and quantity, it will all be taken as an input from user.
any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can use `pyodbc` package. And use variables like: `connection.execute(f"create table {table_name}({column_1}, {column_2})......")` and etc. And use arguments or inputs for variables. `pyodbc` docs: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki

Comment: and what if i want to create multiple table with multiple column on user input so may be i could be doen through loops but how to apply loop on creating table in mssql using python

Comment: Lets assume you want to do it. The user can write it as dictionary `table_name` another input `{'column1': 'varchar(100)', 'column2': 'int'}`. You are checking the dictionary creating the table. Another input `'Do you want to continue: y/n'`. You are checking the input, like while 'Yes' continue the loop. Something like this you can try if you want to try.

Comment: But what you are trying to do is very dangerous, because you are allowing users to create objects in your database without monitoring it. And what about indexes and other stuff, they can crash your database. BI developer or any back-end data developer should do this kind of work.

Comment: actually i am working on a project where i have to create relate multiple data sources (i.e heterogenous like sql, nosql, excel, csv) and relate on a single stage also have to create data schema.

Comment: the logic which i think is to create a pipelines from each datasources which will extract data from different sources through python and load that data into the schema of mssql so that when all data from different sources relate on single stage i can use that mssql for analysis. but the problem occuring is how to implement this logic using python

Comment: and how to write program to create tables and column in mssql without knowing the table and column name because that name will be extracted from the users datasources ( may be i have to create that tables through some type of loop) but how it will implement in python. Any one can help me in these type of issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try to write the code, share it as a question (if you will have) and others will help you to adjust/edit it. Nobody will write whole code for you here from zero. Try to write it by yourself and users will help you for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the sqllite3 package it is possible. All you need to do is run the queries with a connection to your database.

Comment: Considering the OP initially tagged [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:MySQL]] it's unlikely they want SQLite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).